# Changing world size in flame with parallax

Tags: flutter, viewport, flame

I'm using the version 1 release of Flame, and adding a parallax background which works great.

```
// load background layers
final layers = _layersMeta.entries.map(
      (e) => loadParallaxLayer(
    ParallaxImageData(e.key),
    velocityMultiplier: Vector2(e.value.toDouble(), 1.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fill: LayerFill.none ,
      ),
);

// create background parallax
parallax = ParallaxComponent(
  parallax: Parallax(
    await Future.wait(layers),
    baseVelocity: Vector2(20, 0),
  ),
);

add(parallax);
```

Once I set the camera to follow a Sprite `camera.followVector2(player.position);` then its obvious that the parallax was initialized to the size of the screen because as the camera moves, the edges of the parallax become visible with a black game world background. I've tried changing the size of the `ParallaxComponent` and the `Parallax` to no avail.

Changing the canvas size doesn't do much either `onGameResize(Vector2(camera.canvasSize.x, 5000));`

Is there a standard way to set a component fill the world size? The [source code](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/packages/flame/lib/src/game/camera/viewport.dart) talks about the world size, but I don't see any way to control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ParallaxComponent` is a `PositionComponent` which lives in the world that the camera is viewing by default. If you want a `PositionComponent` to be relative to the viewport (or the `GameWidget`) you have to change its `positionType` to `PositionType.viewport`.

So in this case the initialization of your `ParallaxComponent` could look like this to make it ignore the camera:

```dart
// create background parallax
parallax = ParallaxComponent(
  parallax: Parallax(
    await Future.wait(layers),
    baseVelocity: Vector2(20, 0),
  ),
)..positionType = PositionType.viewport;
```

Comment: Odd, it wasn't following the camera by default. When I set it to PositionType.widget though, it follows the camera. The position type is what I was missing, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it unclear, updated the text now.